# Beamer PDF presentation - how can i invert colors easily?

Tags: pdf

Suppose you are going to do a presentacion using a beamer PDF file and you dont know what size the rooms is, neither how much light there is. 
Under this circumstances, it would be better to have a "black on white" (the default) version of the presentation as well as a "white on black" version, and decide which one to use once you arrive at the place. Suppose also that you might need to use another computer and copy the PDF file into it.

Is there a simple way to generate a completely inverted version of the beamer PDF presentation??

Comment: You can set up a command which will allow you to switch the colours included in your presentation easily. Since beamer colour schemes usually depend heavily on inheritance, the number of colours you need to configure may be relatively manageable. However, this will only work if you are careful which external images you use (if any), and take care that any diagrams drawn using LaTeX packages inherit the same colours.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no simple way to invert the colors (like an 'invert' option). But I think you don't need to create a command. You "only" need two color schemes which define inverted colors. Have you ever manipulated color schemes for beamer? Which color scheme do want to use?

Comment: actually basic black and white scheme is sufficient. But i am a little concerned about the eps images that i put into, which are plots or diagrams, i guess they will not invert if i do the change from the beamer source file right?

Answer (score 3):

The [evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) feature «invert colors» (ctrl-i) switch could solve your problem in live during presentation.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your answer to comment on the fact this viewer seems to be Linux-only?

Comment: Evince can be installed on Windows natively, just look in the Downloads link https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince.

Comment: Don't worry, it can be used on BSD too.

Comment: Zathura has the same feature, with Ctrl-R, which actually preserves color tones.